# Deprecated: Non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, php7

estoy usando **PHP 7.2** y estoy viendo la herencia:

Tengo dos clases:

**clasePadre**

```
class clasePadre{
        public function metodoPadre(){
            return "Hola desde el padre";
        }

        public function saludar(){
            return "Hola, soy el padre";
        }
    }
```

**claseHijo**

```
class claseHijo extends clasePadre{

    public function metodoHijo(){
        return self::metodoPadre();
    }

    public function saludar(){
        return "Hola, soy el hijo";
    }

    public function elegirSaludo(){
        return saludar();
    }

}
```

Entonces creo una instancia de la **claseHijo** :

```
$obj = new claseHijo();
```

Con la cual estoy intentando acceder a propiedades del padre

```
echo    $obj->metodoPadre();
```

Eso me imprime `Hola desde el padre` asi que perfecto. Pero al usar de esta manera :

```
echo claseHijo::metodoPadre();

echo claseHijo::elegirSaludo();
```

Me manda el siguiente **error** :

```
Deprecated: Non-static method claseHijo::elegirSaludo() should not be called statically in C:\wamp64\www\CURSO_PHP_OO\herencia.php on line 40
```

Answer (score 4):

Esto es para llamar a un método estático.

```
claseHijo::metodoPadre();
```

Para eso, el metodo tendría que ser `static`.

```
 public static function metodoPadre(){
     return "Hola desde el padre";
 }
```

Sino habría que instanciarlo primero como has hecho o te dará un error (quedó deprecado a partir de la [version 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration56.deprecated.php) de PHP).

```
$obj = new claseHijo();   
$obj->metodoPadre();
```

Comment: Ah perfecto, entonces siempre tengo que hacer `$obj->nombreMetodo();` no ? al menos que sea `static` y sea asi `claseHijo::metodoPadre();`

Comment: Si primero tendrías que instanciarlo y accederías a los metodos con `->`