# Tengo el siguiente error en mi codigo de php

Tags: php

Me aparece este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method Datos::createUsuarioModel() cannot be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso_api\ControllerJason.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\curso_api\ControllerJason.php(26): ControllerJson->createUsuarioController('iker', '9896', 'cliente', 'iker@curso.com') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\curso_api\ControllerJason.php on line 19

```
<?php


require_once "Conexion.php";

/**
 * 
 */
class Datos extends Conexion
{
    
    #USUARIOS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function createUsuarioModel($datosModel, $tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, password, role, mail) VALUES (:usuario, :password, :role, :mail)");


        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datosModel["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datosModel["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":role", $datosModel["role"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $datosModel["mail"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "registro exitoso";
            return true;
        }else{
            echo "no se pudo hacer el registro";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function readUsuariosModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, usuario, password, role, mail FROM $tabla");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("usuario", $usuario);
        $stmt->bindColumn("password", $password);
        $stmt->bindColumn("role", $role);
        $stmt->bindColumn("mail", $mail);

        $usuarios = array();

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>usuarios</strong></td>
        <td><strong>password</strong></td>
        <td><strong>role</strong></td>
        <td><strong>mail</strong></td>
        ';

        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $user = array();
            $user["id"] = utf8_encode($id);
            $user["usuario"] = utf8_encode($usuario);
            $user["password"] = utf8_encode($password);
            $user["role"] = utf8_encode($role);
            $user["mail"] = utf8_encode($mail);

            array_push($usuarios, $user);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$user['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['usuario'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['password'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['role'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['mail'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        echo '</table>';

        return $usuarios;
    }

    public function loginUsuarioModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, usuario, password, role, mail FROM $tabla WHERE mail = :mail AND password = :password");

        $mail = "alex@curso.com";
        $password = "1234";

        $stmt->bindParam(":mail", $mail);
        $stmt->bindParam("password", $password);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("usuario", $usuario);
        $stmt->bindColumn("password", $password);
        $stmt->bindColumn("role", $role);
        $stmt->bindColumn("mail", $mail);

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>usuarios</strong></td>
        <td><strong>password</strong></td>
        <td><strong>role</strong></td>
        <td><strong>mail</strong></td>
        ';

        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $user = array();
            $user["id"] = utf8_encode($id);
            $user["usuario"] = utf8_encode($usuario);
            $user["password"] = utf8_encode($password);
            $user["role"] = utf8_encode($role);
            $user["mail"] = utf8_encode($mail);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$user['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['usuario'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['password'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['role'].'</td>
            <td>'.$user['mail'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        if(!empty($user)){
            return $user;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    #CATEGORIAS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function createCategoriaModel($tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (titulo) VALUES (:titulo)");

        //variables de apoyo
        $titulo = "PERFUMES";

        $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "registro exitoso";
        }else{
            echo "no se pudo hacer el registro";
        }
    }

    public function readCategoriaModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, titulo FROM $tabla");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("titulo", $titulo);

        $categorias = array();

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>titulo</strong></td>
        ';

        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $cat = array();
            $cat["id"] = utf8_encode($id);
            $cat["titulo"] = utf8_encode($titulo);

            array_push($categorias, $cat);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$cat['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$cat['titulo'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        echo '</table>';

        return $categorias;
    }

    public function updateCategoriaModel($tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla set titulo = :titulo WHERE id = :id");

        //variables de apoyo
        $id = 18;
        $titulo = "FUNDAS DE TELEFONOS";

        $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $titulo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "edicion exitosa";
        }else{
            echo "no se pudo hacer la edicion";
        }
    }

    public function deleteCategoriaModel($id, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "categoria eliminada correctamente";
        }else{
            echo "la categoria no pudo ser eliminada";
        }
    }

    #VENTAS
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function createVentasModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (usuario, producto, imagen, costo, fecha) VALUES (:usuario, :producto, :imagen, :costo, :fecha)");

        //variables de apoyo
        $usuario = "10";
        $producto = "consola switch";
        $imagen = "imagen.jpg";
        $costo = "10000";
        $fecha = "2018-05-19 00:22:01";

        $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $usuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":producto", $producto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":imagen", $imagen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":costo", $costo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":fecha", $fecha, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            echo "venta realizada";
        }else{
            echo "no se pudo hacer la venta";
        }
    }

    public function readVentasModel($tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT V.id, U.usuario, V.producto, V.imagen, V.costo, V.fecha FROM $tabla V INNER JOIN usuarios U ON V.usuario = U.id ORDER BY V.fecha");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("usuario", $usuario);
        $stmt->bindColumn("producto", $producto);
        $stmt->bindColumn("imagen", $imagen);
        $stmt->bindColumn("fecha", $fecha);

        $ventas = array();

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>usuarios</strong></td>
        <td><strong>productos</strong></td>
        <td><strong>imagen</strong></td>
        <td><strong>fecha</strong></td>
        ';

        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $ven = array();
            $ven["id"] = utf8_encode($id);
            $ven["usuario"] = utf8_encode($usuario);
            $ven["producto"] = utf8_encode($producto);
            $ven["imagen"] = utf8_encode($imagen);
            $ven["fecha"] = utf8_encode($fecha);

            array_push($ventas, $ven);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$ven['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['usuario'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['producto'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['imagen'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['fecha'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        echo '</table>';

        return $ventas;
    }

    public function readVentasEspecificas($usuario, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT V.id, U.usuario, V.producto, V.imagen, V.costo, V.fecha FROM $tabla V INNER JOIN usuarios U ON V.usuario = U.id WHERE U.id = $usuario ORDER BY V.fecha");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("usuario", $usuario);
        $stmt->bindColumn("producto", $producto);
        $stmt->bindColumn("imagen", $imagen);
        $stmt->bindColumn("fecha", $fecha);

        $ventas = array();

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>usuarios</strong></td>
        <td><strong>productos</strong></td>
        <td><strong>imagen</strong></td>
        <td><strong>fecha</strong></td>
        ';

        while ($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $ven = array();
            $ven["id"] = utf8_encode($id);
            $ven["usuario"] = utf8_encode($usuario);
            $ven["producto"] = utf8_encode($producto);
            $ven["imagen"] = utf8_encode($imagen);
            $ven["fecha"] = utf8_encode($fecha);

            array_push($ventas, $ven);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$ven['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['usuario'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['producto'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['imagen'].'</td>
            <td>'.$ven['fecha'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        echo '</table>';

        return $ventas;
    }

    #PRODUCTOS
    //-----------------------

    public function readProductosModel($tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id, titulo, descripcion, contenido, imagen, precio, calificacion, categoria FROM $tabla");
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bindColumn("id", $id);
        $stmt->bindColumn("titulo", $titulo);
        $stmt->bindColumn("descripcion", $descripcion);
        $stmt->bindColumn("contenido", $contenido);
        $stmt->bindColumn("imagen", $imagen);
        $stmt->bindColumn("precio", $precio);
        $stmt->bindColumn("calificacion", $calificacion);
        $stmt->bindColumn("categoria", $categoria);

        $productos = array();

        //verificar
        echo'
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>id</strong></td>
        <td><strong>titulo</strong></td>
        <td><strong>descipcion</strong></td>
        <td><strong>contenido</strong></td>
        <td><strong>imagen</strong></td>
        <td><strong>precio</strong></td>
        <td><strong>calificacion</strong></td>
        <td><strong>categoria</strong></td>
        ';

        while($fila = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)){
            $pro = array();
            $pro['id'] = utf8_encode($id);
            $pro['titulo'] = utf8_encode($titulo);
            $pro['descripcion'] = utf8_encode($descripcion);
            $pro['contenido'] = utf8_encode($contenido);
            $pro['imagen'] = utf8_encode($imagen);
            $pro['precio'] = utf8_encode($precio);
            $pro['calificacion'] = utf8_encode($calificacion);
            $pro['categoria'] = utf8_encode($categoria);

            array_push($productos, $pro);

            echo'
            <tr>
            <td>'.$pro['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['titulo'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['descripcion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['contenido'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['imagen'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['calificacion'].'</td>
            <td>'.$pro['categoria'].'</td>
            ';
        }

        echo '</table>';

        return $productos;
    }

    public function deleteProductoModel($id, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("DELETE FROM $tabla WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "producto eliminado";
        }else{
            "el producto no pudo ser eliminado";
        }
    }

}


?>
```

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen una pregunta no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @Juan si sabes que puedes editarlo?

Comment: @Christian aunque él lo edite, seguiría siendo una pregunta de baja calidad :) Por eso es mejor que el OP sea quien lo edite y además agregue más detalles: no podemos adivinar el contexto.

Comment: Se que se puede editar, pero siendo una pregunta poco concreta, y con un código ininteligible, no veo lógico editarlo. Creo que  autor podría mejorar la pregunta y los datos.

Comment: El error es que estás tratando de ejecutar un método no estático como estático, con `$variableDeClase::createUsuarioModel()`, solo cambia los `::` por `->` en el archivo `ControllerJason.php`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Deprecated: Non-static method should not be called statically](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255548/deprecated-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-statically)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy viendo tu código en totalidad pero el problema al parecer viene del archivo con esta ruta **C:\xampp\htdocs\curso_api\ControllerJason.php(26): ControllerJson->createUsuarioController**

Si bien no me equivoco no estas llamando el método de la forma apropiada. El error claramente lo dice que estas llamando un método que es no estático en el controlador y es imposible continuar.

En caso de que necesites más ayuda, comenta la parte del controlador :D

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)